# Cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas table and I want to do the following mathematics operation:

```
|label|  area | equivalent_diameter|  mean_intensity|  solidity|
---------------------------------------------------------------
   1    1011       35.878199           255.0          0.863365:
   2    107        11.672045           255.0          0.849206
   3     8         3.191538            76.0           0.800000
   4    18         4.787307            255.0          0.720000
   5    110        11.834541           255.0          0.769231
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to:

```
df['area'] = math.sqrt(df['area]/math.pi)

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

What I did and does not solve the problem:

```
new_data = df['area'].apply(lambda x: float(x))

# and then:

new_x = new_data/math.pi
new_y = math.sqrt(new_x)
```

still given the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
df['area'] = np.sqrt(df['area']/np.pi)
```

Comment: Why it is not worked with math? Thank you, it worked with numpy.

Comment: math contains standard types for python, such as int and float, and when you use that, the interpreter infers a standard division. That fails, because the standard division does not work on the series object. When you have a series from a pandas dataframe, you need to use vectorized operations that work over the complete series, and the interpreter infers that when you use the np.pi constant. By using the np.pi constant you are saying: please divide every element in the series with pi. The same for np.sqrt: please take the sqrt of all elements in the series

Comment: Sorry, I am mistaking for the math.pi part in the comment above. That actually work. But the math.sqrt does not work on the series, only on standard python floats and ints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List comprehension and then equal the data to your data frame. Please try the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
d = {'label': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'area': [1011, 107, 8, 18, 110],
 'equivalent_diameter': [35.878199, 11.672045, 3.191538, 4.787307, 11.834541],
 'mean_intensity': [255.0, 255.0, 76.0, 255.0, 255.0],
 'solidity': [0.863365, 0.849206, 0.800000, 0.720000, 0.769231]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data = df['area']/math.pi
df['area'] = [math.sqrt(i) for i in data]
print(df)
```